# How to add more conditions in where clause?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have made a loop to retrieve conditions:

```
for level in levels:
    requete += ' and level_concat like %'+level+'%'
```

and i made in my query:

```
countries = Country.objects.extra(where=['continent_id = "'+continent_id+'"', requete])
```

I have tried to add condition to my where clause, but return error:

```
not enough arguments for format string
```

Respected results:

```
SELECT * FROM `Country` WHERE country_id = "US-51" AND level_concat LIKE %level_test%
```

Is there a way to add `requete` to my 'where' clause?

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `.extra` rather than `.filter`?

Comment: because `level_concat` is a list of levels concatenated by coma, and `requete` contains also a list of levels. So how to do that with `.filter`

Comment: I don't know whats your list structure is. But anyhow i think you need to escape the `%` sign in your query as `%%` so `' and level_concat like %'+level+'%'` should be `' and level_concat like %%'+level+'%%'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to escape the `%` sign in your query:

```
' and level_concat like %%'+level+'%%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is not a good practice to keep data in a relational database as a "list of [values] concatenated by coma" - you should create a new table for those values.

Still, even now you can use `filter()`, instead of `extra()` (which should be always your last resort - I don't see the rest of your code, but if you don't properly escape `levels` values you may even be introducing an SQL Injection vulnerability here).

An example of a secure, `extra()`-less code, that does the exact same thing:

```
from django.db.models import Q

q = Q()
for level in levels:
    q &= Q(level_concat__contains=level)

countries = Country.objects.filter(q)
```

or the same functionality, but in even less number of lines:

```
from django.db.models import Q

q = (Q(level_concat__contains=l) for l in levels)
countries = Country.objects.filter(*q)
```

You can [read more about Q object in Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).